# reorder a field of a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this table named Employee :

```
IdEmploye    |     Order
    10                1 
    17                5 
    102               6 
    66                77
```

I want to re-order this table into this :

```
IdEmploye    |     Order
    10                1 
    17                2 
    102               3 
    66                4
```

How it's possible in SQL ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server supports the use of ROW_NUMBER(), so this will get you there.

```
UPDATE tbl
SET [Order] = sub.NewOrder
from tbl
JOIN
(select IdEmploye, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY IdEmploye) as NewOrder
 from tbl) as sub
 ON sub.IdEmploye = tbl.IdEmploye;
```

Comment: I shouldn't type without coffee. Edited. Thanks, @GordonLinoff.

Answer (score 1):

You can use *CTE* :

```
with empupdt as (
     select e.*, row_number() over (order by IdEmployee) as seq
     from employee e
)
update empupdt 
     set Order = seq;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a straight update

```
Update tbl
Set Order = IdEmploye
```

Comment: Yeah, in this case it work, but if IdEmploye is not 1,2,3,4 you'r solution doesn't work..